# Is there an App that removes unused classes from frameworks?

Tags: css

So to give you an idea of what it is I am trying to do, OOCSS Framework uses a ton of classes, I'm about to package up a mobile site that is about ~2.5 megs and would like to remove all unused classes from the files. Sure, I could do it by hand but it would be much easier if something like this existed for the future.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a Firefox extension called [**Dust Me Selectors**](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/)

> It extracts all the selectors from all the stylesheets on the page you’re viewing, then analyzes that page to see which of those selectors are not used. The data is then stored in your user preferences, so that as you continue to navigate around a site, selectors will be crossed off the list as they’re encountered.
>   You’ll end up with a profile of which selectors are not used anywhere on the site.

or give **Unused Css** a try

> http://unused-css.com/

---

*from Unused Css site:*

**[Latish Sehgal](http://www.dotnetsurfers.com/Blog/2008/10/02/RemovingUnusedCSSClassesFromYourWebApplication.aspx)** has written a windows application to find and remove unused CSS classes. I haven't tested it but from the description, you have to provide the path of your html files and one CSS file. The program will then list the unused CSS selectors. From the screenshot, it looks like there is no way to export this list or download a new clean CSS file. It also looks like the service is limited to one CSS file. If you have multiple files you want to clean, you have to clean them one by one.

**[Dust-Me Selectors](http://www.sitepoint.com/dustmeselectors/)** is a Firefox extension (for v1.5 or later) that finds unused CSS selectors. It extracts all the selectors from all the stylesheets on the page you're viewing, then analyzes that page to see which of those selectors are not used. The data is then stored so that when testing subsequent pages, selectors can be crossed off the list as they're encountered. This tool is supposed to be able to spider a whole website but I unfortunately could make it work. Also, I don't believe you can configure and download the CSS file with the styles removed.

[**Topstyle**](http://www.topstyle4.com/) is a windows application including a bunch of tools to edit CSS. I haven't tested it much but it looks like it has the ability to removed unused CSS selectors. This software costs 80 USD.

Liquidcity CSS cleaner is a php script that uses regular expressions to check the styles of one page. It will tell you the classes that aren't available in the HTML code. I haven't tested this solution.

**[Deadweight](https://github.com/aanand/deadweight)** is a CSS coverage tool. Given a set of stylesheets and a set of URLs, it determines which selectors are actually used and lists which can be "safely" deleted. This tool is a ruby module and will only work with rails website. The unused selectors have to be manually removed from the CSS file.

[Helium CSS](https://github.com/geuis/helium-css) is a javascript tool for discovering unused CSS across many pages on a web site. You first have to install the javascript file to the page you want to test. Then, you have to call a helium function to start the cleaning.

**[UnusedCSS.com](http://UnusedCSS.com)** is web application with an easy to use interface. Type the url of a site and you will get a list of CSS selectors. For each selector, a number indicates how many times a selector is used. This service has a few limitations. The @import statement is not supported. You can't configure and download the new clean CSS file.

**[CSSESS](http://razorfast.com/2010/11/21/announcing-cssess-the-bookmarklet-that-finds-unused-css-selectors/)** is a bookmarklet that helps you find unused CSS selectors on any site. This tool is pretty easy to use but it won't let you configure and download clean CSS files. It will only list unused CSS files.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention. Dust-me is not compatible with FF v6.0.2

Comment: nowdays, it's hard to keep up with FF as they change major version every 6 month :/