# Provided an html file and css files, is there any IDE that can find and remove unused css classes?

Tags: html, css, ide

Is there any way to automatically delete those unused css classes? Also, can I manage css files more systematically? For example, can I change the class name in a css file and the corresponding class name in the html file will also be changed.

Comment: What IDEs have you looked into? NetBeans has a plethora of extensions that can do just about anything.

Comment: There's at least one tool: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7407220/is-there-an-app-that-removes-unused-classes-from-frameworks

Comment: i suspect it wont be good idea since many website make only few css file and include on ever page ... rater a small website css cab be written in one css file ... for different page ...also there is compressor ... and caching ..

Comment: I imagine Dreamweaver probably could, and you could use a headless browser and some tailored scripts to probably pick some of it out too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using this website to check unused css selectors, you can give it a try http://unused-css.com